# How do I get a custom UIView's origin X?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, uitextfield

I make a custom `UITextfield` and use it in a `UIToolbar`.

Then in the `initWithFrame` of the custom `UITextField` after `[super initWithFrame:frame]`

I try to get the origin X of the custom `UITextField` in the window. But I've tried

```
self.frame.origin.x
self.bounds.origin.x
self.superview.frame.origin.x,
self.superview.bounds.origin.x,
CGPoint point = [self.superview convertPoint:self.frame.origin toView:nil]; return point.x;
CGPoint point = [self.superview convertPoint:self.frame.origin fromView:self]; return point.x;
CGPoint point = [self convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow]; return point.x
```

and all of them return 0.0.

But in the window the `UITextField` is actually somewhere in the middle of the `UIToolbar`. How to get the origin x of the custom `UITextField`?

My code:

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    originalHeight = self.bounds.size.height;
    originalWidth = self.bounds.size.width;

    [self createTableView];

}
return self;

- (void)createTableView
{
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];

    LogDebug(@"Origin x = %f", self.frame.origin.x);
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, originalHeight + 18, originalWidth, 320);

}
```

EDIT:

I figured out the solution for this but still don't know the reason behind this question but I will appreciate if anyone can extend this topic.

In the above code I try to print out the original X of my custom UIView during initialization. Seems the app doesn't know my custom UIView's original point's information.

I thought after this line

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame]
```

I can get the original point information of the custom UIView but I was wrong.

I also found out that

```
self.frame.origin.x
```

has the same effect of

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow convertPoint:self.bounds.origin fromView:self].x;
```

Comment: Can you post the whole initWithFrame: method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read this blog:
[Don’t Message self in Objective-C init (or dealloc)](http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-init/)

which advises not to use message on self during initialization. I agree with the points in the blog and think the problem I had was because I tried to message self in init when self is still in a inconsistent state. I move the `CGRectMake` method of `self.tableView` outside of init and the code work because self's frame and bounds are set up and ready to use.